# Diophantine equation $3x^2+y^2=z$

Tags: diophantine-equations

I am currently facing a Diophantine equation $3x^2+y^2=z$, in which $x$, $y$, $z$ are integers. My major is not math and I am entirely new to Diophantine equation. I googled this but only found questions like $ax^2+by^2=z^2$, which are not the same as mine.

Does any one know how to solve this Diophantine equation? I would be very appriciated if someone could give me some hint.

Comment: I don't understand.  The solutions are all the  triples $(x,y,z)=(x,y,3x^2+y^2)$ for $x,y\in \mathbb Z$.  That is to say, you can pick any $x,y$ you like and then $z$ is determined.

Comment: @lulu maybe a better formulation is: For what z exist integers x and y such that the equation is satisfied.

Comment: Yes, we also realized later that we don't need to solve this equation, as z is just 3x^2+y^2.  However, as mentioned by miracle173, we need to find what z exist intergers x and y such that the equation is satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to find all $z$ that can be written in this form, you can start with the fact (Fermat) that a prime $p$ can be written as $p = x^2+3y^2$ if and only if either $p\equiv 1\bmod{3}$ or $p$ is specifically equal to $3$. [Brahmagupta's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity) then shows that the product of any number of such primes is also representable in this way.

This covers all cases where $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime.  You may also have a common factor $k$ so that $x=kx', y=ky', z=k^2z'$ with the relatively prime numbers $x',y',z'$, satisfying the conditions above but no restriction on $k$.

Comment: 1.)  $p=3 \bmod 3$? 2.) isn't Fermat about $x^2+y^2$

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful reply. We will continue our derivation using your method.